# SQL Server database chooser

Tags: sql-server, c#

I remember I used to use a tool that displayed a form so that any reachable database could be selected, like the initial prompt when you open SSMS. I don't remember if it's a StackOverflow tool, something from Microsoft, or a NuGet thing. Does anyone know what I am referring to?

I mean a tool accessible from the C# level, that is.

Comment: To clarify: this is an add-on to Visual Studio, that lets you add in the selected server to your C# code?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for the `Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI` library.

It can be installed via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI/) if you need it.

Please see [SQL Connection Dialog](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21186/SQL-Connection-Dialog) for sample code using it.